# PHP: How can I turn a mysql TEXT or BLOB type into a string?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a frustrating experience in PHP because I keep getting my MEDIUMTEXT field returned as a non-string string. When I check the variable's type it says it's a string, but it's actually an array, basically a character array so I do:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
  print_r($row["myText"]);
}
```

Which instead of printing out the actual text stored there like "here is a line", it just prints 1. This is confusing because I ask it what it's datatype it and it says string... However if I do

```
$row["myText"][0]
```

It will return "h". I'm totally lost on how I can change this value into a string, I mean I would assume php has some function for it, but I can't find it. I also have no idea why it says it's not an array.

Any ideas?

edit by request

mysql query

```
select * from snippets
```

a print_r:
text is the name of the MEDIUMTEXT column in mysql. The others aren't related

```
Array ( [index] => 1 [name] => a name [language] => english [text] => ) 1
```

edit2:

All the code that produced this error:

```
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$dbname = "TestSnippets";

$dbh = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
$selected = mysql_select_db("snippets",$dbh); 

$records = mysql_query("select * from snippets");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
   echo print_r($row);
}
```

This produces the error every time. All other fields come in perfectly fine. Not the MEDIUMTEXT field however.

edit3:

I tried installing a new webserver (Apache) and a new version of PHP, but it still has the same issue. Interestingly enough when I call php-cgi.exe it returns the data with that variable being output properly. I have zero clue what it could be, the only other this is I could install a different version of mysql. I'll try that tomorrow and report back.

edit4: I solved this myself keeping in mind what I was told here. See my answer to my own question below.

Comment: What happens if you `echo $row["myText"]`?

Comment: can you print_r a full `$row` for us?

Comment: Can you update your question with the SQL query and the full results of a print_r($row)?

Comment: If "text" is the name of the MySQL column, then you need to use echo $row['text']; Also, according to the print_r, the text field is empty. Are you sure there's data in there?

Comment: Yes the data is definitely in there. I can access each element via $row['text'][0] but it will not echo the string itself

Comment: Can you please past here all the original & relevant code?

Comment: So that print_r was just a "print_r($row);" or an "echo print_r($row, true);"? Also, I presume that the print_r was the first line in the while loop?

Comment: Any joy, or are you still stuck? (We can't really help without some more code, etc.)

Comment: Sorry took me a while to hack it together from multiple locations, and see if it still produced the same result.

Comment: You're using $records instead of $result in the mysql_fetch_assoc call.

Comment: okay sorry, typo, fixing it now

Comment: I'd also be very tempted to put the while inside an if(!$result) block with a call to mysql_error in the else.

Comment: I originally had it like that, but there were no errors. The only thing I can think of is a php error in the version I'm using, I'm installing a different version now.

Comment: Yes I did, it turned out to be a dumb error on my part. I had a hidden php tag in the text so it made it all invisible! I set my answer as the approved answer below.

Comment: I don't think I get points for it. If I do then that's not my intent. But yeah, it was the only one that answered my question. Though, that's completely my fault and not anyone else's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow okay so I solved the problem, the problem was that I was incredibly dumb.

I hadn't noticed in the my mysql queries that my test string was actually

```
<? myString" ?>
```

It didn't even dawn on me that php would end up parsing out that statement rather than outputting it. That's why it showed up when I ran php-cgi.exe but not in the browser itself, since the display is a little different.

Wow, just mind blowing. Still, thanks everyone for your help, without you telling me the answer I'd have gone down one wrong path after another.

Mystery solved.

Answer (score 3):

You should simply use...

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
  echo $row["text"];
}
```

...as long as 'text' is the appropriate field in the table you're using. The fact that you're using a medium text is irrelevant as far as PHP (a language that isn't typed) is concerned.

**If this doesn't work, then it sounds like the problems are elsewhere.**

Comment: unfortunately that does not print out the data at all... nothing gets output.

Comment: Perhaps because there's no data in there? Can you check what the same SELECT query returns via the MySQL shell client or phpMyAdmin?

Comment: It's most definitely returning data. There is data in that field for certain, and it will let me handle it if I access each individual letter.

Comment: Where is the data? I can't see it in your print_r dump. The column is definitely empty. Can you post more complete information?

Comment: print_r dump was Array ( [index] => 1 [name] => php include [language] => php [text] => )  I know it looks like text has nothing inside of it, however it's not true. I'm trying to install a different version of php and see if it's some strange bug. We'll see

Comment: Tis a deeply odd one - there's not some weird MySQL client/server version mismatch?

Comment: I don't know, I'm pretty spent for today, I'm going to take up the problem again tomorrow and update the question with whatever progress I made. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

In php you can access strings like arrays. So you can get characters from a string by their index.

so when you call `$row["myText"][0]` on a value that is "here is the line". You get the first the character at index 0 which is "h".

if you call `$row["myText"][6]` you should get "i" for the beginning of is.